# Sharepoint List Item Link

Tags: list, document-library

I am trying to have a system defaulted link upon creation of a new list item link to a document library that searches for a field from the initial list.

For example...
I have a list (list1) that has 3 columns...

```
Company ID | Company Name | Company Documents
```

Example of data:

```
001 | ABC Co | Link
002 | ZYX Co | Link
003 | BAM Co | Link
```

I also have a document library that, when a new document is loaded you have to choose (from list1) a company name to relate to the document.

I want to be able to click on the "Link" from list1 and it bring me to the documents library with filtered information correlating to the Company name from the link in the list.

So if I chose the link from "BAM Co" only documents related to "BAM Co" would be shown via filter in the documents library.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **"Query String Filter"** Web Part , this web part can filter your document library based on the filter passed to library using query string.

[How to use the Query String Url Filter Web Part to filter a SharePoint document library](https://collab365.community/query-string-url-filter-web-part/)

[To Filter SharePoint List View Using Query String Web Part With No Code](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/to-filter-sharepoint-list-view-using-query-string-web-part-with-no-code/)